# Excel show external connection datasource in cell

Tags: excel

I hope I can express the problem clear and concisely enough.

I have an excel with MANY external datasources (created automatically by excel through multiselecting the views/tables).
Each datasource gets/has its own tab.

What I want is on each sheet (e.g. in cell A1) the source of the data (the view or tablename) where the data originates from.
I know I probably have to manually insert the row for that, but that's ok.
So I need a property formula/vba that I can insert in cell A1 instead of typing this in manually for each sheet (I have more than 100 sheets).

Comment: Provide an example of what you want for 1 sheet?